# My git isn't being recognized on react and I don't know why

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwOsI8LtVEQ) on uploading a full stack website on heroku and in the video, after logging in to heroku cli, he typed git init in order to remote connect to his heroku repository on react but when I did it, I got this error message.

[image: React Error]

At first, I thought I didn't install git in react so when I did that and tried again, it still didn't recognise it. so I looked up the error on google and it mentioned that I must correctly set the `PATH`  to my git installation and the recomended path were both `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\` and
`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\`.

I did both of these but it still won't recognise it. what is he doing right that I am doing wrong?

Comment: No. I just asked my question without resolving it first but don't worry, I fixed it now. I deleted it because it was me being stupid but I undeleted it now so other people can learn from my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Just simply reloaded Visual Studio Code.